CMake repeatedly fails to find MPI libraries, succeeds after multiple runs
I'm trying to compile the Elmer FEM repository inside the "MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit" environment on Windows. I'm encountering a bizarre issue where CMake fails to find MPI libraries on the first few runs but eventually succeeds without any changes to the command or environment.
git clone https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem
git checkout 8bff09ddc7a0da78b6ba17b19a9afebe2c7824d7
cd elmerfem
mkdir build
cd build

Here's the CMake command I'm using:
cmake -DMPI_C_LIBRARIES=/mingw64/lib/libmsmpi.dll.a -DMPI_CXX_LIBRARIES=/mingw64/lib/libmsmpi.dll.a -DMPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES=/mingw64/lib/libmsmpi.dll.a ..

On the first run, I get:
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIBRARIES)

On the second run (without any changes):
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES)

On the third run:
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing: MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES)

Finally, on the fourth run, CMake succeeds without any errors.
Each time, it seems to find one more MPI component (C, then CXX, then Fortran) but still fails until the fourth attempt. This happens consistently: if I delete the build directory and start over, the same pattern repeats.
Questions:

What could be causing this behavior?
How can I resolve this issue to make CMake succeed on the first run?
Is this a bug in CMake, Elmer FEM's build system, or my setup?

Environment:

Windows 10
MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit
CMake 3.26.4
GCC 14.1.0
Elmer FEM (commit 8bff09ddc7a0da78b6ba17b19a9afebe2c7824d7)

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. Shouldn't the FindMPI.cmake already be able to find the libmsmpi.dll.a? I wonder why it fails!

What is the output in the CMake Logfiles?

@arved thanks for the comment and my apologies for the late response. Could you be kind enough to help me know which log files I should look into and what should I be looking for inside those files?

Well this depends on your cmake version. Usually after a failed configure cmake writes on the console where the logfiles are to be found.
